# How to use special characters (like hyphen) in destructuring assignment syntax?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-2018

I'm curious of why that seems impossible:

```
const {a, b, 'special-one'} = { a:1, b:2, 'special-one': 3 };
// output => missing : after property id
```

Will it be possible to find that syntax working in future ES versions ?

Thanks for your lights :)

Comment: This is impossible because '-' is a special character, and this in case, an operator at that.

Comment: `special-one` is not a valid variable name. You couldn't access this variable afterwards. You'll need to alias it at least.

Comment: Nit-pick: this isn't "spread syntax", it's "destructuring assignment".  You might want to update the question title.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Rename the variable within the destructure statement, you can't have a variable with a hyphen in it's name.  You can rename using the syntax below, see [MDN: Assigning to new variable names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Assigning_to_new_variable_names)

> A property can be unpacked from an object and assigned to a variable
>   with a different name than the object property.

```js
const {
  a,
  b,
  'special-one': specialOne
} = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
  'special-one': 3
};

console.log(specialOne);
```

Comment: The rules for allowed variable names can be found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types#Variables).

Answer (score 3):

`special-one` can't be the variable name. So you need another name for that like `specialOne`. Use `:` after the key name for new variable name.

```js
const {a, b, 'special-one':specialOne} = { a:1, b:2, 'special-one': 3 };
console.log(specialOne)
```

In the above case you have a plain string as key name. But if there is an expression you will need to use `[]`

```js
let keyName = 'special-one'

const {a, b, [keyName]:specialOne} = { a:1, b:2, 'special-one': 3 };
console.log(specialOne)
```